# UML Component diagram: Dangling interfaces or connecting two

Tags: uml, diagrams, component

I'm a novice in UML component diagrams.

How would I draw the following situation?

I have an << item >> called "DataAquisition". This item consists of a << unit >> called "driver". The driver requires an interface to the device, which is connected to the physical device. This is modeled by passing the interface through ports all the way up to the system level and is connected to the provided interface by the physical device. So far so good.

The driver also provides an interface for data readout which is only connected to the "surrounding" DataAq item. The DataAq item iteslf requires an interface to the DataConsumer. So I now have the situation, that I need to turn a provided interface in a required interface. How do I do this? Just leave it dangling and it's clear that the "glue logic" of the DataAq does this? Just connect it?

Edit: The interface consists of a packet generator and a mailbox/data queue to which packets are pushed from multiple different DataAq items.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should simplify it. I think you should use it as a high level view to highlight how different components interact and hide implementation details.

On one side, you could remove the interface as a component. Could be considered as part of the data acquisition component. Or if it's important then you can represent it, but imo if there is nothing special about that interface, then it can be considered just some implementation detail. On the other side if you connect DataAquisition to more components with different interfaces, then you can represent it.

In the end there is no right or wrong, it depend on what you are trying to highlight; but as a rule of thumb, try not to over-complicate it.